# MS ACCESS 2007 - Making a small pop form not full screen, when all other forms are full screen

Tags: ms-access, forms, ms-access-2007

So I am sure that this is a very simple question, but I cannot figure out how to do it so here goes:

I have an Access database that basically has many forms that were designed to display full screen (I guess its the tabbed view in the options). I want to make a Splash screen for these guys but with Access 2007 it will not let me dictate the size of the form. I make the background of the detail small, and it still covers half the screen?

So what am I missing. 2003 was different from this.

Thanks
Justin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Popup property to Yes?  It's in the "Other" tab of the form properties.

Also, if you want to create a splash screen for your entire application, try creating a bitmap file with the same name as your database and save it in the same directory as your database.  (For example, if your DB is example.accdb, create a file name example.bmp in the same directory.)  Not sure if this works in 2007, but it did in past versions of Access.

Comment: The bmp suggestion will work in 2007 and 2010 as outlined by JohnK

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in tabbed view, make sure that your form is not maximized when you save it in design mode. Or it will open maximized in view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the pop-up property to yes does take the form out of the tabbed view, but it also sits on top of any other form that you open.  clicking on the other form does not send the pop-up form to the back.   The graphics for the splash screen still works in 2007, but does not solve certain basic problems, like the ability to fire code from the close event when the application is closed.

Comment: I just followed the tip from JohnK813's answer and tested it.  In MS Access 2007 I have changed my forms to popups and can click on any form behind the open form.  The only thing that keeps me from click other forms behind the popup is setting the form's Modal property to Yes.